# WPF Application Complex Skin 

Tags: wpf, skinning

I'm trying to figure out how to skin an application with a complex resource.

I have a skin file in which I put `Canvas` that contains the complicated artwork. Like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="MainBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Canvas Width="1440.000" Height="900.000">
                <!-- complicated artwork here -->
                </Canvas>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I load this skin into the main app? I'm thinking something like this:

```
<Window>
    <Canvas Style="{StaticResource MainBackground}"/>
</Window >
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use a `Canvas` to lay out controls explicitly. Use the other `Panel` types (such as `Grid` and `DockPanel`).

Secondly, you can import a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Or you can merge in multiple `ResourceDictionary`s as follows:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="YourOtherDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeLocalResource">Red</SolidColorBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Comment: My question is a little different: I've a xaml file (converted from a AI) that is a vector image converted full of canvas and other polyline... I want to use this as background.

Comment: This answer does not address the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly: You can create a visual brush from the exported XAML file's root visual, and use it as the brush of another canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question ... but there are several way to go about this. In the hope that this will help a Google searcher, I will share two ways.

**First of all, you could simply put a Viewbox around that Canvas** (that you got from a converted .ai file). Be aware that you may have to monkey with the Stretch and alignment properties in order to get it to behave as you wish ... but most likely you would set Stretch to UniformToFill and the alignment properties to Center:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="BackgroundSkin.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="640"
    Height="480"
>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Viewbox
            Stretch="UniformToFill"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
        >
            <!-- Replace the following Canvas with yours. -->
            <Canvas Background="White"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Secondly, if you would rather have something more shareable (such that you could use it as the background on several Windows), you could create a Brush out of that artwork.** There are a couple ways to do this. The first is simply to realize that you can use Expression Design to convert the .ai file into a DrawingBrush (i.e. Expression Design can export in two main ways: Canvas/Shape(s) or ResourceDictionary/Brush(es)).

If you don't have the original .ai/.design file for re-exporting, you can create a VisualBrush off of the Canvas (as @Ugar Turan suggests). Note that you will again likely have to monkey around with the Stretch property (and other properties) this time on the VisualBrush:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="BackgroundSkin.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="640"
    Height="480"
    Background="{DynamicResource backgroundBrush}"    
>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Replace the following Canvas with yours. -->
        <Canvas x:Key="backgroundCanvas"/>
        <VisualBrush
            x:Key="backgroundBrush"
            Visual="{DynamicResource backgroundCanvas}"
            Stretch="UniformToFill"
        />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```